# Fast hash function for long string key

Tags: c++, hash-function

I am using an extendible hash and I want to have strings as keys. The problem is that the current hash function that I am using iterates over the whole string/key and I think that this is pretty bad for the program's performance since the hash function is called multiple times especially when I am splitting buckets.

**Current hash function**

```
int hash(const string& key)
{
    int seed = 131;
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        hash = (hash * seed) + key[i];
    }
    return hash;
}
```

The keys could be as long as 40 characters.

**Example of string/key**

```
string key = "from-to condition"
```

I have searched over the internet for a better one but I didn't find anything to match my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: 40 chars isn't that long. And the current hash function you use doesn't have any advantages over those in the std libs. Last time I checked, MSVC was using FNV1a for strings, which shouldn't be any slower than yours, but much better for hashing. I didn't check but GCC probably use the same.

Comment: your hash is **bad**. It can easily overflow, and integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: No it can't (well, unless ULONG_MAX == INT_MAX, which is a pretty pathological implementation.  In fact, I don't think it's legal.)  The calculation is done in `unsigned long` for which overflow is perfectly defined.

Comment: Well I found it on the internet. I guess I' ll have to find another one.

Comment: @UmNyobe The fact that his hash is bad has nothing to do with overflow. As already said, unsigned overflow is perfectly defined. Almost all hashing algorithms use overflows.

Comment: @MartinBonner Indeed it is not undefined behavior, but wrap around. I missed the unsigned

Comment: Quite apart from how you hash the characters, one option for increased speed is to select a fixed number spaced evenly along the string: Visual C++ does exactly this, combining ten characters sampled along the string.  Such a hash won't work well with some keys (e.g. filenames where most is fixed and some is e.g. incrementing numbers).  (GGC uses MURMUR32 for a massively stronger hash, and prime numbers of buckets rather than VC++'s powers of two).

Comment: I have upvoted this question because I think it helps to highlight a common problem with developers - we're all enthusiastic problem solvers. But sometimes (often) the problem is not the one that's immediately obvious. In almost all cases the answer to "I need a better [hash]" should be "why do you think that?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prefer to use `std::hash` unless measurement shows that you can do better.  To limit the number of characters it uses, use something like:

```
    const auto limit = min(key.length(), 16);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < limit; i++)
```

You will want to experiment to find the best value of 16 to use.

I would actually expect the performance to get worse (because you will have more collisions).  If your strings were several k, then limiting to the first 64 bytes might well be worth while.

Depending on your strings, it might be worth starting not at the beginning.  For example, hashing filenames you would probably do better using the characters between 20 and 5 from the end (ignore the often constant pathname prefix, and the file extension).  But you still have to measure.

Answer (score 3):

> I am using an extendible hash and I want to have strings as keys.

As mentioned before, use `std::hash` until there is a good reason not to.

> The problem is that the current hash function that I am using iterates over the whole string/key and I think that this is pretty bad...

It's an understandable thought, but is actually unlikely to be a real concern.

> (anticipating) why?

A quick scan over stack overflow will reveal many experienced developers talking about caches and cache lines.

(forgive me if I'm teaching my grandmother to suck eggs)

A modern CPU is incredibly quick at processing instructions and performing (very complex) arithmetic. In almost all cases, what limits its performance is having to talk to memory across a bus, which is by comparison, horribly slow.

So chip designers build in memory caches - extremely fast memory that sits in the CPU (and therefore does not have to be communicated with over a slow bus). Unhappily, there is only so much space available [plus heat constraints - a topic for another day] for this cache memory so the CPU must treat it like an OS does a disk cache, flushing memory and reading in memory as and when it needs to.

As mentioned, communicating across the bus is slow - (simply put) it requires all the electronic components on the motherboard to stop and synchronise with each other. This wastes a horrible amount of time [This would be a fantastic point to go into a discussion about the propagation of electronic signals across the motherboard being constrained by approximately half the speed of light - it's fascinating but there's only so much space here and I have only so much time]. So rather than transfer one byte, word or longword at a time, the memory is accessed in chunks - called *cache lines*.

It turns out that this is a good decision by chip designers because they understand that most memory is accessed sequentially - because most programs spend most of their time accessing memory linearly (such as when calculating a hash, comparing strings or objects, transforming sequences, copying and initialising sequences and so on).

What's the upshot of all this?

Well, bizarrely, if your string is not already in-cache it turns of that reading one byte of it is almost exactly as expensive as reading *all* the bytes in the first (say) 128 bytes of it.

Plus, because the cache circuitry assumes that memory access is linear, it will begin a fetch of the next *cache line* as soon as it has fetched your first one. It will do this while your CPU is performing its hash computation.

I hope you can see that in this case, even if your string was many thousands of bytes long, and you chose to only hash (say) every 128th byte, all you would be doing would be to compute a very much inferior hash which still causing the memory cache to halt the processor while it fetched large chunks of unused memory. **It would take just as long - for a worse result!**

> Having said that, what are good reasons not to use the standard implementation?

Only when:

1. The users are complaining that your software is too slow to be useful, and
2. The program is verifiably CPU-bound (using 100% of CPU time), and
3. The program is not wasting any cycles by spinning, and
4. Careful profiling has revealed that the program's biggest bottleneck is the hash function, and
5. Independent analysis by another experienced developer confirms that there is no way to improve the algorithm (for example by calling hash less often).

**In short, almost never.**

Comment: Note that using 100% of CPU time doesn't mean the program is CPU-bound. When the CPU stalls for cache or memory access, it will still be counted as CPU time. You need a deeper analysis than the "%" to distinguish CPU-bound and memory-bound.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `std::hash`[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash) instead of implementing your own function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

size_t hash(const std::string& key)
{
    std::hash<std::string> hasher;
    return hasher(key);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << hash("abc") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See this code here: https://ideone.com/4U89aU

Comment: That's a great point of departure, but this is implementation defined and *if* too slow some tips on how to write a fast(er) hash function might be sensible...?

Comment: @TonyDelroy I am sure there is huge amount of computer science works for phd in finding faster hash function. and each believes their is the best. you will need a whole separate website with test cases and discussions at length which would need years to mature.. or you can just use std::hash

Comment: @BoppityBop: all true, but this specific question asks for a string hash function that doesn't iterate over the entire string (..."over the whole string/key and I think that this is pretty bad for the program's performance").  Using `std::hash<>` is abdicating control of that implementation aspect.   It so happens that GCC and clang's implementations will iterate over the entire string, and Micrtosoft Visual C++'s Standard Library will not (but what it does do - picking 10 characters evenly spaced throughout the string, isn't helpful for ~40 character strings). Seems you're say Q is too hard?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mzHash32, a very simple, fast function with a number of collisions very close to an ideal Universal Hash Function

```
uint32_t mzhash32(const int8_t *data, int length, uint32_t seed)
{
    uint32_t hash = 0x95DE1432 ^ seed;
        
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        hash = 0xA8657C5B * (i + data[i]) ^ (hash << 2) ^ (hash >> 2);
        
    return hash;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash32

64 bit version: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash64